# Logical error: Unable to determine the cause of segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
    for (i = (routeVector.size () - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << "Connected to -> " << routeVector[i].exitPoint;
        for (j = (routeVector.size () - 1); j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector.size() > 0)
            {
                cout << "\n: routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector[0].connectedExitPoint" <<
routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector[0].connectedExitPoint;

                ******cout << "\nrouteVector[j].exitPoint:" << routeVector[j].exitPoint;
                if (routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector[0].connectedExitPoint == routeVector[j].exitPoint)
                {
                    cout << "Connected to -> " << routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector[0].connectedExitPoint;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The stared line is giving me a segmentation fault, I fail to understand why.

If the "**routeVector**" had nothing in "**selectedBranchesVector**", it wouldn't have even reached the inside if.

What can be the cause of the said problem?

***EDIT 1:***

To make the problem more clear, I printed out the two conditions of the statement and the error is shown on the stared line.

The structures are:

```
typedef struct branch
{
    unsigned int distance;
    int          connectedExitPoint;
} branch;

typedef struct route
{
    int    exitPoint;
    vector <branch> selectedBranchesVector;
} route;

vector <route> routeVector;
```

Comment: What it the type of exitPoint and connectedExitPoint members?
If it is class, problem could be also in operator==() function of it.

Comment: @User1 I have modified the code, see above.

Comment: What is type of i and j? If the type is unsigned and `routeVector` is empty, then `(routeVector.size () - 1)` would be positive.

Comment: @User1 - as I said in my answer, I'd guess this to be the problem as well..

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code you are showing. The problem is therefore in the code you are not showing. Please post a minimal, complete, compilable, runnable example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @User1 i and j were unsigned int, and that was the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependent on the type of `i` and `j` - if `i` and `j` are `unsigned`, the above loops will loop back around quite happily - which is probably what is going on - print the indexes and you'll see...

Comment: ... and the reason for the segmentation fault is that the program is accessing a route vector element out of the bounds.

Comment: @Nim Indeed, that was the problem, many thanks. i and j were `unsigned int`.